# How to perform a 8-way de-interleave in neon

Tags: arm, neon, intrinsics

In the neon intrinsics,there are four intrinsics(vld1 vld2 vld3 vld4) to perform 1-way to 4-way de-interleave.But how to implement 8-way de-interleave?

For example, the data is:

````
uint8_t src[64] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,```63};
````

Load data into neon register, and after performing 8-way de-interleave,I hope the value of src_reg1 and src_reg2 could be like this:

````
uint8x8x4_t src_reg1;
uint8x8x4_t src_reg2;
src_reg1.val[0] = {0,8, 16,24,32,40,48,56}
src_reg1.val[1] = {1,9, 17,25,```}
src_reg1.val[2] = {2,10,18,26,```}
src_reg1.val[3] = {3,11,19,27,```}
src_reg2.val[0] = {4,12,20,28,```}
src_reg2.val[1] = {5,13,21,29,```}
src_reg2.val[2] = {6,14,22,30,```}
src_reg2.val[3] = {7,15,23,31,39,47,55,63}
````

Does anyone know how to achieve this?Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as doing two 4-element loads to get two sets of 4-way deinterleaved data, then further deinterleaving those sets with each other via one of the register-interleaving operations, e.g.:

```c
uint8x8x4_t src_reg1 = vld4_u8(src);
uint8x8x4_t src_reg2 = vld4_u8(src + 32);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // This a bit of a faff thanks to the intrinsic datatypes, but
    // compiling at -O3 tidies it all up into sensible code
    uint8x8x2_t tmp = vuzp_u8(src_reg1.val[i], src_reg2.val[i]);
    src_reg1.val[i] = tmp.val[0];
    src_reg2.val[i] = tmp.val[1];
}
```